# Spring AOP Exclude Some Classes

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I'm using Spring AspectJ for logging method execution statistics, however, I want to exclude some classes and methods from this without changing the pointcut expression.

To exclude certain methods I created a custom annotation which I use to filter out. However I'm unable to do the same with classes.

Here is my aspect definition -

```
@Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.web.controller.*.*(..)) "
            + "&& !@annotation(com.foo.bar.util.NoLogging)")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // logging logic here
}
```

`NoLogging` is my custom annotation for excluding methods.

So how can I filter out certain classes without changing pointcut expression and without adding new advisors?

Comment: i think that's not possible, execution will match your definition and it is loaded at begining. Maybe you can try to create a new @Around aspect and check if it overrides previous one. But I am not sure of it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution - use `@target` PCD (pointcut designators) to filter out classes with specific annotation. In this case I already have the `@NoLogging` annotation so I can use that. The updated pointcut expression will then become as follows -

```
@Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.web.controller.*.*(..)) "
            + "&& !@annotation(com.foo.bar.util.NoLogging)" 
            + "&& !@target(com.foo.bar.util.NoLogging)")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // logging logic here
}
```

Explanation -

`execution(* com.foo.bar.web.controller.*.*(..))` - all methods of all classes in `c.f.b.w.controller` package

`"&& !@annotation(com.foo.bar.util.NoLogging)"` - which do NOT have `@NoLogging` annotation on them

`"&& !@target(com.foo.bar.util.NoLogging)"` - and whose class also does NOT have `@NoLogging` annotation.

So now I simply have to add `@NoLogging` annotation to any class whose methods I want to be excluded from the aspect.

More PCD can be found in Spring AOP documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: Hi, is it possible to also add your @NoLogging custom annotation implementation, I am having trouble to filter out methods from similar avoid logging scenario.

Comment: @harmonious the annotation doesn't contain any logic. You can find it over here - https://github.com/harshilsharma63/controller-logger/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/logger/controller/annotation/NoLogging.java

Comment: @harmonious also, I've created an open source library for handling all of AOP based logging logic. You can check it out at https://github.com/harshilsharma63/controller-logger. Maybe it already fulfills your task?

Comment: Thanks @harshil-sharma I got it to work with: `@Target(ElementType.METHOD )
public @interface NoLogging {
}`

Answer (score 4):

As per [Spring AOP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

> PCD can be &&'ed, ||'ed, and ! (negated) too.

So I guess this is more of trial and error exercise. I think you can try something like `&& !@within` @within is applicable for types. Or you can try `!@target`

But then again I think it could be tricky.

Another approach: declare two pointcut definitions and combine them. And example, [here on the documentation page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-or-xml). I would try this first. Something like

```
@Pointcut(executionPC() && nonAnnotatedClassesPC() && nonAnnotatedMethodsPC())
```

Disclaimer: As I said, this looks more like trial and error. And I don't have a clear working example.